# How to take average of each line

Tags: awk

I have data like this. I would like to take averages like the output:

```
1. 800
2. 900 
3. 1000
4. 1100
5. 1200
```

This command does not work as I expected. It shows 0 for all. Could anyone help me to correct it?

```
cat tcat test.txt | awk '{ sum=0; for (counter = 1; counter >= 5; counter++) sum+=$2; print sum/counter}'
```

Expected output

```
1  800 # 800/1
2  850 #(800+900)/2
3  900 #(800+900+1000)/3
4  950 #(800+900+1000+1100)/4
5 1000 #(800+900+1000+1100+1200)/5
```

Comment: The loop `for( counter = 1; counter >= 5; counter++)` will execute zero times.  You probably  meant `counter <= 5`.  But this (modified) loop runs 5 times for each line of input, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following.

```
awk '{print $1,($2+sum)/FNR;sum+=$2}' Input_file
```

***OR*** in case your first field's DOTs you want to remove like your shown samples then try following a little tweak in above code:

```
awk '{sub(/\.$/,"",$1);print $1,($2+sum)/FNR;sum+=$2}' Input_file
```

***OR*** if your shown examples `1.`(first fields) and so on is just for reference then use $0 as follows:

```
awk '{print ($0+sum)/FNR;sum+=$0}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `print` function of `awk` in which printing `$1`(first field) along with value(sum of 2nd field with sum and divide this with $2), then keep on add the 2nd field value into sum variable(as per requirement).

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk '{printf "%d %4d\n", NR, (s += $NF)/NR}' file
1  800
2  850
3  900
4  950
5 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN {    __ = ++_ / (_ - (_ += ++_)^-( ++_*_ + _^!_) ) 
>       ___*= CONVFMT = "%\04720.10f" } $(_=NF) = (___+=$_) * __/NR'
> ```

```
1.       800.0000000000
2.       850.0000000000
3.       900.0000000000
4.       950.0000000000
5.     1,000.0000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$2} END{for(i in a){n+=a[i]; print i,n/i}}' file
1 800
2 850
3 900
4 950
5 1000
```